# What are the kashrut standards of the various nationwide (and regional) kashrut agencies?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, hechsher-certification, organizations

I'd like to see a resource developed which *transparently* compares the standards of the various kashrut agencies. Just like I can retrieve an incredibly in-depth comparison chart from Wikipedia regarding my choice of [word processing programs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_word_processors), I would love to have a similar comparison of kashrut agencies. For instance, a comparison of standards regarding:

- Pat Akum
- Glatt
- Operation on Shabbat and holidays
- Frequency of supervised visits
- Bug checking

The Jewish community should challenge its kashrut agencies to make their policies clear and transparent.

QUESTION: What are the (stated? verifiable?) standards held by various kashrut agencies? OU, OK, CRC....

Answer (score 2):

[Kashrus Magazine](http://www.kashrusmagazine.com/) has the most thorough investigative articles about every aspect of Kashrut supervision and practices. Their coverage of issues with salmon, raisins, and supervision in Israel was enlightening.  The alerts and listings are more than worth the subscription.

This independent resource is the best approach I know to get into the minds, practices, policies, and standards of the Kashrut agencies.

Dis/claimer: I'm not affiliated with Kashrus Magazine. I didn't even pay for it ... my mother-in-law sent us a gift subscription.